# Is there a way to download this homestead virtualbox file?

Tags: amazon-s3, vagrant, homestead

### Short Question

I am currently trying to install Homestead.  The following url is choking me to death

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/2.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box

Is there any other way to download the above file ?

### Details:

The above file download is redirected to signed S3 url. Out of great wisdom, there is a timeout of 60 [perhaps in second] .. so after downloading 10% or , the download fails.

Have a look at the following :

```
vagrant init laravel/homestead; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
...
==> default: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v2.1.0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/2.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> default: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
    default:
           An error occurred while downloading the remote file.
           The error message, if any, is reproduced below.
           Please fix this error and try again.
```

I have tried downloading the file using other means, e.g through the browser or through curl. The call to the above url results in a signed S3 link, which in all its glory has a timeout as you can see in the I get the following url :: .

```
https://hc-prod-storagelocker.s3.amazonaws.com/boxes/5b64bd3b-eb87-4af4-9b2d-1c1560efca67?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJBKZ6DNPERBCPYKQ%2F20170613%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170613T022000Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=0d13db989138a93b4ab82d18c4768b141e837d0c834654f73f5394e1cd04ce0e
```

Even though I am not sitting under a rock, but they clearly think that I should have better speed,  hence such a short expiry of the signed url.

Comment: Have you talked to the people that put up the link?  That's a lot easier than writing code to download in 60 second chunks using a new starting position each time.

Comment: I thought about talking to them .. I don;t know how to. Here is the link I could get to 

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead 

and thats it.

Comment: did you retry ? I am able to download the box without any issue

Comment: Oh yes - I have retried multiple times yesterday and twice this morning. The download starts as normal. On average I do get up to 100MB of the file out of 880MB depending on how good my connection is .. and then it dies.

Comment: My latest attempt is to use chunks .. 

curl  https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/2.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box  -r 0-1000000 -L -o ./homestead-1000000.box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to slow connection, the download kept breaking. Even though vagrant says:

```
Box download is resuming from prior download progress
```

there was no indication from progress percent that it was actually resuming.

I kept on trying, by running it over and over again .. and eventually it accounted for previous download progress.

Comment: Ran into the same issue and I did what you said, ran it over and over again, probably over a dozen times. Eventually it was able to download it all.